# Meteor: Cordova Android app stuck on loading screen

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

So I'm creating a meteor app, almost finished, then I'm trying to run it on my android phone, with

```
meteor run android-device
```

The app start on my android but unfortunately it stuck in the my loading screen, as if the waitOn function never end.
PS: The phone and my computer are on the same network, I can access the app from my phone if I start it normally with

```
meteor --port 3000
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue, I had to set a server for the app to connect to with:

```
meteor run android-device --server xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
```

Comment: Flag is no longer --server, it is --mobile-server